# Rails: How to add add_index to existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, migrate

I already migrated a table called units with several columns. I was wondering how to migrate in a stand alone 'add_index' to this table using the cmd. Is this code correct:

```
class AddIndexToUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :units, :lesson_id
  end

  def self.down
    remove :units
  end
end
```

I have a feeling the self.down could be wrong, I am unsure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The self.up method is correct. Use this for your self.down:

```
remove_index :units, :column => :lesson_id
```

Comment: thanks :D, seems like you guys have slightly different answers

Comment: The difference is that Yule gives a name to the index in his self.up which he uses for removing it. The code I provided removes the index based on its column name.

Answer (score 10):

Almost

```
class AddIndexToUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :units, :lesson_id, :name=>'lesson_index'
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :units, 'lesson_index'
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! :) how do I add this from the command line: rails generate migration add_index_to_units  doesn't work

Comment: What exactly does not work? A new migration file is not created?

Comment: a file is created but it looks really weird... like has 2 add_columns in the self.up definition

Comment: @Arsen I'm not sure you can do this directly from command line. Is there a reason you can't just edit migration file?  If not checkout https://github.com/capotej/migration_for. Seems to do what you're after...

Answer (score 2):

To remove an index, you must use `remove_index` with the same table and column specification as the self.up's `add_index` has. So:

```
def self.down
  remove_index :units, :lesson_id
end
```

A multi-column index example would be:

```
def self.down
  remove_index :units, [:lesson_id, :user_id]
end
```