# Best way to add_index to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following two migrations already in my database:

**When I created Prices:**

```
class CreatePrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :prices do |t|
      t.string :price_name
      t.decimal :price
      t.date :date

      t.timestamps
    end
    # add_index :prices (not added)
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :prices
  end
end
```

**and when I added a user_id to Prices:**

```
class AddUserIdToPrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :prices, :user_id, :integer
  end
  # add_index :user_id (not added)
end

  def self.down
    remove_column :prices, :user_id
  end
end
```

Is there a way from the command line to add prices and user_id to index? I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108340/rails-how-to-add-add-index-to-existing-table) and still was confused on how to go about adding indexes and the parts where I put "not added" seem like they would be error-prone because they were earlier migrations.

My question is, what is the best way for me to add indexing to prices and user_id?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have a look at this Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087350/rails-3-database-indexes-and-other-optimization/6088297#6088297

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think one extra migration fits well:

```
class AddIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    add_index :prices, :user_id
    add_index :prices, :price
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :prices, :user_id
    remove_index :prices, :price
  end

end
```

Or you can use `change` syntax with newer versions of rails, look at `DonamiteIsTnt` comment for details:

```
class AddIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    add_index :prices, :user_id
    add_index :prices, :price
  end

end
```

Comment: To generate the migration skeleton: `rails g migration AddIndexes`

Comment: @Michael Witrant Thanks for showing me how to get to that point!

Comment: @Edgerunner Thanks, this was very easy to get.

Comment: Isn't the down method supposed to be the inverse of the up? so down should be "remove_index :prices, :price" and then "remove_index :prices, :user_id". Order matters, no?

Comment: no order doesnt matter. Actually with Rails 3.1 or higher you can just write `def change end` without up or down

Comment: Note that until Mikhail (nudge) updates this answer, [the primary way of writing migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method) is via the change method. That is, assuming you are using one of the "reversible migrations" listed in that link. You just write a change method (and no up method) and rails infers the "down" method automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Once an app is in production, the intent is that migrations will be applied *once*.

If you're still developing your app, you can always add them as you've noted followed by a `rake db:migrate:reset` **this will wipe your database and re-create it**.

Otherwise, create a new migration `rails g migration add_user_id_index`.

```
class AddUserIdIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :prices, :user_id
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :prices, :user_id
  end
end
```

FWIW, `add_index :prices` doesn't make sense. Indexes are per-column, not per-table.

You can always manually create indexes by logging into your database.

```
CREATE INDEX prices__user_id__idx ON prices (user_id);
```

Comment: Could i still index a table though?

Comment: Indexes must be defined on a table for one or more columns, listed explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution:

- create a new migration
- add the indexes there (they don't need to be in the older migrations)
- run the migrations